# MYSQL: make 1 query from 2

Tags: mysql, merge

How I can merge this 2 querys to 1?

```
 $query1 = mysqli_query($_connect, 'SELECT `id` FROM `callers` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1') or die();
 $result1 = mysqli_fetch_object($query1);

 $query2 = mysqli_query($_connect, 'SELECT SUM(`calls`) AS "total" FROM `callers`') or die();
 $result2 = mysqli_fetch_object($query2);
```

Now I have:

`$result1->id` for the last **ID**
and
`$result2->total` for a Sum of all **calls**

For that results I have 2 querys, my queation: Is it possible to run 1 query and have both result?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. These two queries are simple instead of having one ugly one, and there's no performance advantage to one query because of what these queries do.

Comment: I understand but, 2 querys are 2 connections to the database and every unnecessary connection is one connection too many when a server have lots of total connections.

Comment: `2 querys are 2 connections`...no. You only have one connection, which is already open. Running a second query doesn't make a new connection. The cost of sending a new SQL query to the database is tiny compared to opening a new connection.. KIKO is right, there is no real downside in having 2 queries here instead of 1

Comment: @ADyson I think they mean 2 round trips to the DB.

Comment: @Barmar possibly, or possibly not. It's not an uncommon misconception

Comment: While it's generally recommended to minimize the number of queries you make to the DB, unless you're doing this frequently it won't make much difference. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've got to take back what I wrote before, because I think there is a more optimal way to combine these two queries:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(`id`) AS `highest_id`,
  SUM(`calls`) AS `total`
FROM `callers`;
```

Note that using `MAX()` gets the single highest id, just like your first query does (correction from MIN() thanks to [user1191247](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191247/user1191247)).

However, unless you runs these queries tens or hundreds of time per second, you won't notice a big improvement.

Comment: Basically, it's about minimizing queries to the database and server connections in general from the outset. I think that at some point, when there are a lot of simultaneous connections and queries, it will be worth it. You also have to keep in mind that not everyone has their own server and endless resources, but still has a lot of visitors to the website. I realize that this thing alone doesn't achieve anything or not much, but what if there are a lot of requests at the same time? I try to minimize problems from the outset that could come later. Saving can never be wrong...my opinion...

Comment: @BeKu I agree, I always try to optimize my code like this. Just wanted to emphasize that this only represents a small improvement. There must be bigger fish out there in your code? Perhaps [composite Indexes](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/mysql-composite-index/) you missed? I manage big databases and found that partitioning tables can make a big improvement to some queries. Or what about using in-memory SQLite for complicated queries? I'm talking factors more speed instead of a few percent. But you're right, small things do add up in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can join the two queries.

```
$query = mysqli_query($_connect, '
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT `id` FROM `callers` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1
    ) AS t1
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT SUM(`calls`) AS "total" FROM `callers`
    ) AS t2');
$result = mysqli_fetch_object($query);
```

You can then use `$result->id` and `$result->total`.